# Select2: Tags not working properly with custom DataAdapter

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using a custom dataAdapter and also trying to use the 'tags' attribute in Select2 jQuery plugin. But the exemple found in the documentation is not working at all, the 'tags' attribute is simply ignored (this is only happening when using a custom dataAdapter, otherwise it's working fine).

So this is not working:

```
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true
});
```

As a solution for this, I've found out we can use a decorator for Tags in the dataAdapter, and it really works! Problem is, it will always work. So if I have two 'select' tags in HTML, and I want one of them to have 'tags:true' and the other one to have 'tags:false', they'll both have tagging enabled because of this decorator. I've tried setting 'tags:false', but it's not working.

I'm thinking a solution would be in the dataAdapter, to create an if statement for the decorator, for it to be applied or not. But then the problem is that this specific code is executed only once, when the first 'select' is created.

So I'm thinking that if I use a dataAdapter for creating multiple selects, all of them will have the same decorators. And I don't think having multiple dataAdapters would be a solution for me.

So my question is, if I have multiple 'select' elements, how can I use different decorators applied for each of them? Also using the same dataAdapter?

I also have a JSFiddle for this:
[Tags with dataAdapter](http://jsfiddle.net/v18tLc17/80/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We have just run into this as well and I have been unable to find anything on how to "correctly" implement this. Feel there is a pattern or hook I'm missing that select2 should provide [here](https://select2.org/advanced/adapters-and-decorators).

I've come up with 2 ways of handling this.

#### 1. Handle adding the decorators up front of calling select2

```
(function ($) {
    var CustomDataAdapter = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/data/customDataAdapter');
    var Utils = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/utils');
    var Tags = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/data/tags');
    var MinimumInputLength = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/data/minimumInputLength');
    
    $.fn.mySelect2 = function(options) {
        if (!options.dataAdapter && options.customDataAdapterOptions) {
            options.dataAdapter = CustomDataAdapter;

            if (options.minimumInputLength > 0) {
                options.dataAdapter = Utils.Decorate(options.dataAdapter, MinimumInputLength);
            }

            if (options.tags) {
                options.dataAdapter = Utils.Decorate(options.dataAdapter, Tags);
            }
        }

        return this.select2(options);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Usage changes to: `$('selector').mySelect2(options);`

#### 2. Override the Defaults.apply method that handles this for built in dataAdapters

```
(function() {
    var CustomDataAdapter = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/data/customDataAdapter');
    var Utils = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/utils');
    var Tags = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/data/tags');
    var MinimumInputLength = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/data/minimumInputLength');
    var baseApply = $.fn.select2.defaults.apply;

    $.fn.select2.defaults.apply = function (options) {
        if (!options.dataAdapter && options.customDataAdapterOptions) {
            options.dataAdapter = CustomDataAdapter;

            if (options.minimumInputLength > 0) {
                options.dataAdapter = Utils.Decorate(options.dataAdapter, MinimumInputLength);
            }

            if (options.tags) {
                options.dataAdapter = Utils.Decorate(options.dataAdapter, Tags);
            }
        }
        return baseApply.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}());
```

Usage does not change: `$('selector').select2(options);`

Comment: Thanks. I have the same problem. This answer is awesome, but if i have `dataAdapter: myCustomAdapter` option, then i have to modify the conditons. Yours replys on `options.customDataAdapterOptions`